# Wordpress: How do I fix my post class?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I seem to have somehow messed up when wordpress calls the post class. I looked in "Main Index Template" but that just says "`<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">`" So I don't know what to do.

Comment: You really need to clarify that; your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: lol @ your question asking skills

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the id's and class name not printing out on the front end?

Add an echo like the example below so that the id and class is printed out.

```
<div <?php echo post_class() ?> id="post-<?php echo the_ID(); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more information but If something has gone wrong because of you editing the files then I would suggest you to replace the file from www.wordpress.org.

If it is s theme file then replace the theme.